# Crossword: My favourite puzzlers

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

### *Who are two of my favourite puzzlers on Puzzling.SE?*

Complete the crossword below to find out.  A **complete answer** will provide the names of ***two*** of my favourite puzzlers on Puzzling.SE as well as the **completed crossword**.

There is a twist here, but I'll leave it up to you to figure out what it is.

---

I have attempted to follow the conventions of *New York Times* crosswords when it comes to the clues, but I'm sure there are a few places where I haven't quite succeeded, so please keep an open mind...!

For those who want to print and work on it, [here is a one-page printable version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2nno0fkjgcx6t1/FavouritePuzzlers.pdf?dl=0).

[image: Crossword grid]

<sup>***Across:***

1. Bad end for a tooth?

5. Formal sanction

16. Word with "box" or "muscle"

19. Nocturnal critter

20. Like some cuisine

21. _____ the ground

22. World Cup cheer

23. Inflection

25. Untested

26. Extinct bird

27. Eyeballs or moons, e.g.

28. It has bark but no bite

30. Frivolous escapade

32. Graveside music

34. Stern direction

37. Daytime TV choice

41. All in ______ work

42. *Ghostbusters* Ph.D. Spengler

44. Nighttime annoyance

45. Along with *storge* and *philia*, kin of 35 Down

48. Island on the Croatian coast of the Adriatic Sea

49. Provoke to anger

51. Part of GPS coords.

52. Add a little colour to

53. Prefix meaning "personal, private"

55. California wines

56. Family reunion attendee

58. *Petro-Canada* competitor

59. Type of 7-line poem

61. With gravity

63. Means of manual propulsion

64. Burn soother

65. Penned

66. In a languid manner

68. Food store

71. One of only two types of egg-laying mammals

74. Beasts of burden

75. ______ of rubbish; a falsehood

76. One of only 5 on Earth

77. Skip out on someone

79. Prefix with *kind* or *made*

80. State of disbelief?

82. *Narcissus pseudonarcissus*, e.g.

86. Where the sun rises in Cancún

88. Setting with knights and castles

89. Forcibly remove

91. Lean and tough

92. Ladies' fingers

93. Sis, bro, or cuz

94. Close to the bullseye

96. Protocol for server storage (abbr.)

97. (He) knows, according to Jaques

98. Tools for the links

101. Half the title of a Kasabian song

102. Greek muse

104. Ingredient in Chinese soup

107. You'll find several in intensive care units

108. Inventor of dynamite

109. Indigenous animals

111. "____ of wine, a cigarette, and then it's time to go" - Leonard Cohen

113. Jacob's twin

114. Started, as a fire

115. Potential PETA cry

119. Vena cava, e.g.

125. Fuss and bother

126. Draw up

127. It's just across the strait from Morocco

128. ____'clock: coffee break time

129. Ratio word

130. ________ trend: eschews the latest fad

131. Miss in Mex.</sup>




<sup>***Down***:

1. Play part

2. Baby sound

3. Type of *ex gratia* payment

4. Verve

5. Court officials

6. Off-road transport, for short

7. However, poetically

8. Common computer configuration file type

9. Library section, briefly

10. Cake shop employees

11. Greek sea

12.  _____ and feather

13. Rage

14. Potential salary in sales (abbr.)

15. Poetic present

16. Metaphors, e.g.

17. Soothing plant

18. Stern, on land

24. Extremely large

29. Daughter of Hyperion

31. Sharp mountain ridge

32. Bathsheba's lover

33. _______ taw a puddy tat!

34. Chastise

35. See 45 Across

36. Outfit for Octavian?

38. Cornmeal porridge

39. Agent of divine communication

40. Piranha boss in Nintendo's Mario games

43. Wilder ending?

46. Marked down

47. 2010 Indian rom-com: *I hate luv _______*

50. Stutterer's dissent

54. WWII landing site: _____ Beach

56. Stereotypical Puzzling.SE user

57. Blacksmith's medium

60. ____ up: drunk, slangily

62. Gemini, e.g.

66. Street kid

67. "I'm _____ walker, but I never walk back." - Abraham Lincoln

68. Walk-on roles

69. Home of Nome

70. Many a member of Puzzling.SE

71. Level of hierarchy

72. Middling grades

73. Hospital illnesses (abbr.)

76. Not me or you

77. Kevin and Francis

78. Rears, to a sailor

80. Pungent

81. With "chow", a delicious dish

82. Matt in *Dogma*

83. Ones who correct misconceptions

84. Livid

85. Certain disinfectant

87. Eschew takeout

90. One of my favourite Puzzling.SE puzzlers

95. On edge

99. Almost at

100. Serpentine sound

103. Uses a spit

105. Gospel, soul, blues, or funk (abbr.)

106. Its capital is Lhasa

109. Part of an envelope

110. Assistant

112. Pro

113. Nights before

116. Spanish gold

117. Fairy

118. MMA org.

120. Leftover morsel

121. Exclamation of awe

122. Printer resolution

123. Tolkien creature

124. Mauna ____</sup>

**Hint:**

> Did you have any "wrong" guesses when completing the puzzle, especially around the area of 90D?  Perhaps you should explore those more. Compare your answers with other solvers. Did they get the same results?

Comment: Could you please include the number of letters against each clue. Makes it hard to keep scrolling back and forth.

Comment: @CodeNewbie, that's not standard crossword policy (except cryptic crosswords).  Try the PDF version linked just above the crossword grid if you want a more compact version.

Comment: Think your grid is missing the number 89, unless that's somehow part of the twist.

Comment: @BaileyM It should be obvious where the 89 belongs (directly below 81).  It's not intentional; just a mistake on my part.

Comment: I saw it missing on the grid and actively checked to make sure there was a clue to go with it. :) I figured as much, but wanted to point it out in case.

Comment: I'll save you guys the trouble of solving the crossword: the answers are NeedAName and @Roland, aka the Puzzling Twins. Why? Because how could it not be us!?

Comment: @NeedAName LOL ;-)

Comment: Well, I've found one of his favorites so far, and it's not me :( I worked my way down the right side, but I fear my lunch break is over. So I'll get around to finishing this evening! Don't spoil it for me in the meantime :)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain is 34A 'bat'? If so, I've completed it.

Comment: @BaileyM Apparently I made a mistake.  34A is in fact "bat".  The puzzle went through a few iterations, and apparently I left in an old clue (for the word "aft").  So you are correct.

Comment: Oh, good! :D Then now all that's left is figuring out your twist, and the second puzzler...hmm...

Comment: I want to think that rearranging the puzzle somehow makes the black squares spell something out. If you mirror the center creatively, you get a heart...

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain any chance we get a hint on this next part? I'm super stuck.

Comment: @BaileyM I gave you a (very subtle) hint on you answer when I said *what you've completed so far* is correct. I'll add a hint to the puzzle description.

Comment: Hm, I think I know it - it must be something similar to the (in)famous BOBDOLE/CLINTON crossword.

Comment: Too bad the second favorite puzzler didn't get to see the answer.  In his last comments on the site, he said he was pretty much giving up on the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, now that [everyone](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20790/crossword-my-favourite-puzzlers/21913#comment65847_20790) [else](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20790/crossword-my-favourite-puzzlers/21913#comment65852_20803) has done [99% of the work](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/20803/5208), allow me take the glory... The second puzzler is:

> **JLee**

Because:

> There's several alternative answers you can use for the following:
>  **81D** - With "chow", a delicious dish - **MEAN** ("this is some *mean chow*")
>  **82D** - Matt in Dogma - **DEMON** (Matt Damon plays the part of Loki, a demonic figure)
>  
>  **89A** - Forcibly remove - **EJECT**
>  **94A** - Close to the bullseye - **ALMOST**
>  **101A** - Half the title of a Kasabian song - **NEON** (from the song "Neon Noon")
>  **107A** - You'll find several in intensive care units - **ENS** (there's two types of nurses Registered Nurses and Enrolled Nurses, or RNs and ENs)

<sub>...I guess you couldn't fit Alconja into a four letter space anyway...</sub>

Comment: I figured as much, but I refused to admit the second puzzler wasn't me :(

Comment: @BaileyM - Don't worry, we'll go make our *own* crossword... I note that BaileyM and Alconja have the same number of letters.

Comment: Good luck making those cross haha

Comment: @BaileyM - Pfft. How hard could it be? **5A** - inappropriate way to refer to women in the workplace (hoe/hon), **6A** - a type of food (jam/yam)... practically writes itself.

Comment: @Alconja, until you try to fit them all into a crossword; then it becomes a lot more difficult. I originally intended to have several pairs of puzzlers in the puzzle, but after getting it to work for the 4-letter ones, I lowered my expectations.

Comment: ENS was intended to refer to the letter N. There are several in "intensive care units".

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - I was of course being facetious. :) I can only imagine how hard it would be to do properly. (well done btw)

Answer (score 10):

### Partial Answer

It's close to a final answer... but I'm missing the twist and a final favorite puzzler...

Anyways, here's the grid:

[image: crossword grid]

***ERRATA***: 96-Across should be 'SAS', not 'NAS'. That makes 83-Down 'DISABUSER'. (Thanks @Kingrames)

The first favorite puzzler is **xnor**, who's the answer to 90-Down. As I've already mentioned, the second puzzler to this point eludes me.

Comment: What you've completed so far contains one error.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain oh god D: I guess I'd better find that then

Comment: It's in the lower-right quadrant.  Check your Down clues.

Comment: here's to hoping the second puzzler is "whoever solves it." ...waitaminnute, how can there only be one error? If a letter is wrong, isn't it two errors?

Comment: Is it disabuser (instead of dinabuser)?

Comment: @Kingrames AH, that's it. Not a word I'm familiar with, nor a protocol I know. Thanks!

Comment: @BaileyM Yes, Kingrames got it.  With that change, everything you have so far is correct.

Comment: I am victorious!

Comment: So for anyone looking for some sort of twist, 'aloe' is used twice in the grid, and 'iron' and 'irons' are both used. I don't know if either of those mean anything though.

Comment: My guess is that there's an alternate answer for the clues near 90 Down. 89 Across being "eject", 94 Across being "almost", or something like that to make the second puzzler JLee (?).